# Exception Unable to build entity manager factory

Tags: java, hibernate

I was following a tutorial example on hibernate, but there was a problem and already googled and could not resolve.
Here's the problem:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at br.com.k19.jpa.GeraTabelas.main(GeraTabelas.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
... 4 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
... 34 more
```

And the code is this:

```
    package br.com.k19.jpa;

        import java.io.Serializable;

         import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.Id;

        @Entity
        public class Editora implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8315827950813041429L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
      }

The class should generate a database table:

    package br.com.k19.jpa;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    public class GeraTabelas {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory ("livraria-pu");
        factory.close();
    }
    }
```

And the persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="livraria-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"   value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"       value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/livraria" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

My persistence is in src/META-INF folder

Comment: Is your database up? Are you able to access it externally, e.g. from command-line?

Comment: Yes I created the database in mysql through the terminal. The base is on localhost and mysql came installed on the system. I use Slackware Linux 14.1

Comment: I even thought it was problem of user restriction, but in my persistence.xml I'm using root and password is correct.

Comment: `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` That suggests that it is not able to connect in the first place. Whether the user/pass is correct/incorrect comes next.

Comment: So I'm using the correct jars.

Comment: antlr-2.7.7.jar                                hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                                jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar                         javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar  jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar

Comment: hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar                 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.3.5.Final.jar              jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar        mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
hibernate-envers-4.3.5.Final.jar               slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar

Comment: Solved the problem! Believe it or not. The problem was caused by this file: /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld

I am using the version of mysql that came installed on slackware linux 14.1
Server version: 5.5.32-MariaDB MariaDB Server

So I commented the following line in the file:
SKIP="-skip-networking"

Then I just restart the service.
bash-4.2# /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld restart


The problem was not related to java.

Comment: Just an FYI, I'd recommend removing your Hibernate Dialect setter. Hibernate does an outstanding job selecting its dialect based on the driver you pass in. This means that if the driver gets updated (unlikely but you never know) Hibernate can update its dialect when you redeploy without you having to do anything. The dialect setter is a relic from when Hibernate didn't have the automatic dialect detection.

Comment: @PattersonSilva: Sounds great that you found the solution. Also rather than just leaving your question unsolved, you should post your solution as the answer. And also go ahead and accept your answer to mark it as solved. Who know in the future it might help someone in the similar situation.

Comment: I needed enough points, to answer my own question. Now I have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! Believe it or not. The problem was caused by this file: /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld

I am using the version of mysql that came installed on slackware linux 14.1
Server version: 5.5.32-MariaDB MariaDB Server

So I commented the following line in the file:
SKIP="-skip-networking"

Then I just restart the service.
bash-4.2# /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld restart

The problem was not related to java.